# How to enable code completion of Angular in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, code-completion

I am new Angular and I use Visual Studio to modify Angular code. 
Below is the image of the current situation of my IDE.

[current code outlook img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyQxi.png)

As you can see, the code of mainly Angular stuffs is not traced by my IDE.
I searched a little bit about this and feel like that I can enable it from intellisense, but in my intellisense, I could not find some choices that I can make to change this. The image of my current intellisense is as below.

[my intellisense img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhuV4.png)

Can someone tell me what I should do?

Comment: may be you need to install : [angular-productivity-pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=devboosts.angular-productivity-pack)

Comment: I have shifted to Visual Studio Code and it works properly right now.